# Binary constraint in non linear optimization in R (NLOPTR - COBYLA)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve a non linear optimization problem using NLOPTR library in R. Within NLOPTR, I am using COBYLA algorithm. Some of my constraints are binary and I am not able to specify it in NLOPTR.

Consider two values x, y. My requirement is as follows,

1. x can be 0 or 1.
2. y can be 0 or 1
3. x + y = 1        #so that one of x/y is 0 and the other one is 1.

If any of you has specified similar problem in Non-Linear Optimization, please help. If there is a better library to use, kindly suggest it.

Thanks / Sandeep

Comment: You are looking for an MINLP solver. I don't think NLOPTR has one.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen do you know what library to use in R for this problem. I did lot of research but failed to get a solved example or right library in R.

Comment: MINLP solvers are readily available, but R interfaces are rare or nonexistent.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen indeed, i didn't find anything in R. Can you tell me which softwares or languages have built in library for solving this. Maybe Pyhton ?

Comment: You can try a few MINLP solvers online at [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html)